# Hamiltonian diffeomorphisms on a Poisson manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, diffeomorphism, poisson-geometry

Let $(M,\{-,-\})$ be a Poisson manifold.

> An **Hamiltonian isotopy** is a smooth family of diffeomorphisms $\{\varphi^t:M\to M\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ such that $\varphi^0=\text{id}_M$ there exists a smooth family of functions $\{h_t:M\to \mathbb{R}\}_{t\in [0,1]}$ such that
> $$\frac{d\varphi^t(x)}{dt}=X_{h_t}|_{\varphi^t(x)}$$
> where $X_{h_t}$ is the Hamilton vector field induced by $h_t$ (i.e. $X_{h_t}(g):=\{h_t,g\}$ for any $g\in C^\infty(M)$).
>
> A diffeomorphism $\varphi:M\to M$ is a **Hamiltonian diffeomorfism** iff there exists an Hamiltonian isotopy $\{\varphi^t\}$ such that $\varphi^1=\varphi$.

I want to prove that the set of the hamiltonian diffeomorphisms $\text{Ham}(M)$ is a subgroup of the diffeomorphisms group. In order to do so my reference book ("Lectures on Poisson Geometry" by Crainic, Fernandes, Marcut) suggests proving that given two hamiltonian isotopies $\{\varphi^t\}$ and $\{\psi^t\}$, we have that $\{\varphi^t\circ \psi^t\}$ and $\{(\varphi^t)^{-1}\}$ are hamiltoniana isotopies, but I'm having some trouble in proving this.

**My attempt**
Let $\{h_t\}$ and $\{k_t\}$ be smooth families associated to the hamiltonian isotopies $\{\varphi^t\}$ and $\{\psi^t\}$.
I define the functions $\psi_x(t):=(t,\psi^t(x))$ and $\tilde{\varphi}(t,y):=\varphi^t(y)$. Clearly
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=t_0}(\varphi^t\circ \psi^t)(x)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=t_0} (\tilde{\varphi}\circ \psi_x)(t)=d_{t_0}(\tilde{\varphi}\circ \psi_x)\left(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=t_0}\right)= $$
$$=\left(d_{\psi_x(t_0)}\tilde{\varphi} \circ d_{t_0}\psi_x\right)\left(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=t_0}\right)=d_{\psi_x(t_0)}\tilde{\varphi}\left(1;X_{k_{t_0}}|_{\psi^{t_0}(x)}\right)=$$

And now I feel a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the composition, you can check
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4248516
where the corresponding Hamiltonian vector field and its smooth family of functions are constructed.

You can now use this and the fact that $\varphi_t^{-1} \circ \varphi_t=id_M$ to show the result for inverses. You just need to plug $Z_t=0$ (the vector field associated to the Hamiltonian isotopy $\varphi_t=id_M$ for all $t$) along with its corresponding family of smooth functions being constant functions (so that the Poisson bracket is zero). If $h_t$ and $X_t$ correspond to $\varphi_t$, then $-h_t\circ\varphi_t$ and $-(\varphi_t^{-1})_* X_t(\varphi_t(x))$ would make $\varphi_t^{-1}$ a Hamiltonian isotopy from $\varphi_0^{-1}=id^{-1}=id$ to $\varphi_1^{-1}=\varphi^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but there's just a point that's not clear to me. When we have to prove that $X_{h_t}+(\varphi^t)_\ast X_{k_t}=X_{h_t+k_t\circ (\varphi^t)^{-1}}$ we use the fact that an hamiltonian diffeomorphism is also a Poisson diffeomorphism (so it's compatible with the Poisson bracket). This is true but it was not yet proven in my book. How do you prove that an hamiltonian diffeomorphism is also a Poisson diffeomorphism?

Comment: Sometimes Hamiltonian isotopies are defined as a certain type of Poisson isotopies, in which case it follows from the definition, e.g. see page 38 in https://doi.org/10.1016/S0926-2245(01)00042-0. Btw, Proposition 4.2 there would also be an answer to your question, with different notation. I know this is not an answer, but you might be able to translate this formulation to yours and therefore understand why a Hamiltonian diffeomorphism is a Poisson morphism.